# rails3 unscoped within the model gets overriden by default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have this model

User.rb

```
default_scope :order => 'users.created_at DESC'
```

and

```
scope :ranking, lambda { unscoped { order('users.ranking DESC') }}
```

and still I get a to_sql that includes `ORDER BY users.created_at DESC, users.ranking DESC`...

can someone explain why?

I really don't want to have to call unscoped from every controller i'll be using this model in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're discovering, `default_scope` is often more trouble than it's worth. If you're wanting to stick with it, you could use `reorder` to ignore the previous order:

```
scope :ranking, reorder("ranking DESC")
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why @TimPost deleted my answer but I'm using rails 3.0.5 and ruby 1.9.2 for a project and when I used reorder(which works btw) it says this in the log

DEPRECATION WARNING: reorder is deprecated. Please use except(:order).order(...) instead. (called from `<class:Item>`

So I don't think it is fair my answer was deleted and I got dinged for a crappy response

Comment: I can see your deleted answer, it reads, and I quote: `reorder is deprecated and doesn't remove a limit on the default scope.  Any other ideas on how to remove the entire`; where it suddenly ends.  Two reasons for it to be deleted: 1) You don't finish your second sentence.  2) It looks like your second sentence is actually attempting to ask a question on how something should be done instead.  *Answers* on SO should never be asking questions like that -- they should be new questions in their own right.

Comment: Kirk,  Thank you for clarifying.  I apologize for that and next time I'll make sure to do a better job.